# How to connect MongoDb in Xcode

Tags: mongodb, swift4

**I want to connect the MongoDb in my xcode** use the pod file **pod 'MongoSwift'** but still it's not working. Given the error, while Install & Update all the required the mongodb driver

```
brew install mongo-c-driver
```

> 'mongoc.h' file not found
>   Could not build Objective-C module 'libmongoc'

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1047

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman not working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its too late but nonetheless, try updating to the latest cocaopod. Cocaopod now supports automating taking care of the required frameworks for you.

Install the latest stable version of cocoapods

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Update it

`pod setup`

Reinstall your MongoSwift by deleting, `pod install`, adding back and `pod install` again.

It should work now, at least for me.